# Logistic regression outputs equal coefficients, std error and t values for every categorical variable after creating dummies. Why is that?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, linear-model

I have a dataframe with 700 rows and for each row I have dummy variables.

The dataframe looks like this

```
  0 1 2 3
1 1 0 0 0
2 0 0 0 1
3 0 1 0 0
4 1 0 0 0
.....
```

This is my `X`.

As the target variable I have a floating number between 5.5 and 10, this is my `y`.

I then fit a linear regression on this data.

```
X2 = sm.add_constant(X)
est = sm.OLS(y, X2)
est2 = est.fit()
est2.summary()
```

This outputs the following table:
https://gyazo.com/adb010b46cabc785168f0235aa967379

Why are all the values equal? Does this mean there is no predictive power in the data?

Comment: The problem is not so much that they are equal, but that they are extremely large. (They may not be equal at all, just differ in lower figures.) It seems like you have massive collinearity. Looking at your `X`, is it possible that *every* row sums to 1?

Comment: Also, why do you have "logistic" in your question? Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry about the logistic, that is a mistake! Yes, they all sum to 1. They are dummy variables. Is there anyway to correctly deal with this? Sorry for my stupid questions

Comment: No problem. If you have dummy variables for $k$ predictors or categories, you can *either* use an intercept and only $k-1$ dummy columns, *or* use all $k$ dummy columns without an intercept. So your solution is simply not to add the constant, working with `X` instead of `X2` (which you don't need at all).